# How do I move a unique pointer from one vector to another vector of unique pointers?

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, unique-ptr

How do I move a `unique_ptr` from one vector to another vector of `unique_ptr`s in C++11? The unique pointer from the first vector should be completely removed and added to the second vector.

Comment: Depends. Should it replace an element, be inserted at a specific position, or what? What should happen with the original?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly learn how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @Deduplicator Edited question. The unique pointer from the first vector should be completely removed and added to the second vector.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in that case you have two conceptually independent operations:

1. Inserting an element into a container. As you want to obliterate the source (which is actually necessary because `std::unique_ptr` is a move-only type), use `std::move` to enable move-semantics.

   ```
   destination.emplace(destination.begin() + m, std::move(source[n])); // or .insert()
   ```
2. Removing the plundered element from the container.

   ```
   source.erase(source.begin() + n);
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`<algorithm>` contains an implementation of [`std::move`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/move).

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v1;
v1.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(1));
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<int>> v2;
v2.emplace_back(std::make_unique<int>(2));

std::move(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));

for (auto &&e : v2)
    std::cout << *e;
 // Prints 21
```

After this execution, `v1` will contain 1 element with the nullptr value.